# How to call super.super method in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following classes

```
class Animal
  def move
    "I can move"
  end
end

class Bird < Animal
  def move
    super + " by flying"
  end
end

class Penguin < Bird
  def move
    #How can I call Animal move here
    "I can move"+ ' by swimming'
  end
end
```

How can I call Animal's move method inside Penguin ? I can't use super.super.move. What are the options?

Thanks

Comment: Accepted solution is not the best way to go if you love _designs_. Best answer is - [How can we call parent's parent method in Ruby(elegant way) ?](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/429729).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the `move` instance method of `Animal`, bind it to `self`, then call it:

```
class Penguin < Bird
  def move
    m = Animal.instance_method(:move).bind(self)
    m.call
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Ruby 2.2.0, then you have something new in your plate. That *something* is : [`Method#super_method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-super_method).

```
class Animal
  def move
    "I can move"
  end
end

class Bird < Animal
  def move
    super + " by flying"
  end
end

class Penguin < Bird
  def move
    method(__method__).super_method.super_method.call + ' by swimming'
  end
end

Penguin.new.move # => "I can move by swimming"
```

I completely agree with [`Robert Klemme's`](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/429729) and his answer is best and clean.

Comment: That's rather cool.  If convenient, you could also do this: `class Method; def ancestor_method(n); n.times.reduce(self) { |m,_| m.super_method }; end; end`, then `method(__method__).ancestor_method(2).call + ' by swimming'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Penguin < Bird
  def move
    grandparent = self.class.superclass.superclass
    meth = grandparent.instance_method(:move)
    meth.bind(self).call + " by swimming"
  end
end

puts Penguin.new.move
```

For more details about this approach read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4557614/2649456)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this (which I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739582/does-calling-super-cause-further-methods-in-the-parent-class-to-be-used)):

```
class Penguin < Bird
  def move
    puts self.class.ancestors[2].instance_method(__method__).bind(self).call +
    ' by swimming'
  end
end

Penguin.new.move
  # I can move by swimming
```

[Edit: I see this is quite similar to @August's answer. This has the slight advantage that neither the class `Animal` nor method name `move` are hard-wired.]